# How to run *BOTH* black and autopep8 *AUTOMATICALLY* upon saving a Python file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, flake8, autopep8

Under the `settings.json` file in VS Code, I've got `black` set as the Python formatter:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,    
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "--line-length",
    "120"
],
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length",
    "120",
    "--in-place"
],
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Args": [
    "--max-line-length",
    "120",
    "--ignore=E501",
]
```

`Black` does a fantastic job formatting Python code, but unfortunately any `flake8` errors are not corrected by `black`.
So Flake8 errors like `Expected 2 blank lines, found 0 (E302)` are not fixed upon saving a `.py` file in VS Code.

Fortunately those Flake8 errors CAN be fixed if you run `autopep8 --in-place <your_python_script.py>`
but obviously this is annoying as it requires an extra manual step.

So the natural question is:  how to enable BOTH `black` and `autopep8 --in-place` to run and trigger upon saving any `.py` file?

My understanding is that VS Code has a setting `python.formatting.provider` that you can set to `black`, or `autopep8`, or `yapf`, etc.  But it only accepts a single formatting provider, and not two.

How to configure VS Code to apply more than one formatter to Python files upon saving those files?

Alternatively, is there a way to trigger `autopep8 --in-place` to be triggered upon saving a Python file (in addition to the black formatter)?

Comment: I suspect you're using an outdated version of flake8 -- black should basically fix everything except E501 and E203 at the current version

Comment: also you want `--extend-ignore` not `--ignore` for flake8

Answer (score 0):

note this configuration when working with black you'll want to use black's [recommended settings](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/06ccb88bf2bd35a4dc5d591bb296b5b299d07323/docs/guides/using_black_with_other_tools.md#flake8)

```
max-line-length = 88
extend-ignore = E203
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't @MingJie.  I want black to not just identify the flake8 errors but to also *fix* them, similar to how `autopep8 --in-place` fixes those errors.


I would just simply run both `black` and `autopep8 --in-place` in sequence, but this feels inefficient to run two commands that should easily be performed with a single command.

Comment: I think you can put forward it here: https://github.com/psf/black